# SFINAE for std::reference_wrapper constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

The implementation of `std::reference_wrapper` in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) has the following constructor. Can someone explain what `detail::FUN<T>(..)` does or provide some detail as to what this SFINAE construct is trying to accomplish? Is this just to make sure `U&` is convertible to `T&`?

```cpp
    namespace detail {
      template <class T> constexpr T& FUN(T& t) noexcept { return t; }
      template <class T> void FUN(T&&) = delete;
    }
    // construct/copy/destroy
    template <class U, class = decltype(
        detail::FUN<T>(std::declval<U>()),
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<reference_wrapper, std::remove_cvref_t<U>>>()
    )>
    constexpr reference_wrapper(U&& u)
        noexcept(noexcept(detail::FUN<T>(std::forward<U>(u))))
        : _ptr(std::addressof(detail::FUN<T>(std::forward<U>(u)))) {}
```

Comment: you have missed the part where `detail::FUN<T>` is declared. As a matter of fact, there are two overloads of `detail::FUN` one taking a reference and returning reference, another taking an rvalue-reference and returning `void`. `decltype()` is used to deduce the resulting type of the `detail::FUN` that is chosen by the compiler, and is compared with `U`. I suppoose it is used to customize the function based on `U` being a reference or an rvaliue-reference

Comment: I did see the definition earlier, but have added it to the question. It's still not clear as to the intent. BTW the second overload is a forwarding or universal reference vs. r-value ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`detail::FUN<T>(std::declval<U>())` performs an overload resolution on the overloaded set of function templates `detail::FUN<T>` with an argument of type `U&&`. If that overload resolution selects `constexpr T& FUN(T& t)`, then the type of its return value is ignored, since the call is the first operand to a comma operator. If it selects `void FUN(T&&)`, then since this is a deleted function, it means `detail::FUN<T>(std::declval<U>())` is ill-formed; this is a substitution failure and the constructor is removed from the overload set.

The practical consequence is that `std::reference_wrapper<const T>` is not constructible from an rvalue of type `T` or `const T`, nor any other expression that would prefer to convert to `const T&&` rather than `const T&`, because in those cases, the converting constructor shown has a substitution failure.

See [LWG 2993](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2993) for an explanation of why this is so complicated.